# Как вызвать внешнюю команду из python-скрипта?

Tags: python, cmd

Как в программе python послать запрос в командную строку?

Например, команду "pip install bot_vk"

Comment: https://proft.me/2009/04/9/zapusk-vneshnih-prilozhenij-v-python/

Answer (score 3):

```
from os import system
system('pip install bot_vk')
```

Comment: а как потом ввести например "y" или "n", например когда удаляешь модуль?

Comment: @Иван, 
Не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: но вот я послал команду system('pip uninstall bot_vk'). Если делать это в консоли, то дальше появится строка Would remove : bla bla bla, 
Proceed(y/n). Тут я должен ввести y(удалить) или n(не удалять). Как это сделать?

Comment: @Иван, используйте `system('pip uninstall bot_vk -y')`

Comment: а есть ли вариант в 1 командную строку послать 2 команды?

Comment: @Иван, В Linux `cmd_1 && cmd_2` или `cmd_1; cmd_2`. В первом случае вторая команда выполняется в случае если первая завершилась без ошибок, во втором обе команды выполнятся в любом случае. Как в винде не знаю.